# PHPDoc not showing folders for packages?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

I name my classes as such:

```
Folder_SubFolder_SubFolder_ClassName{}
```

Which as we all know, creates a folder directory as such: `Folder/SubFolder/SubFolder/ClassName.php`

Now I document this class as such:

```
/**
 * Some title
 *
 * Some Description
 *
 * @package Folder_SubFolder_SubFolder
 */
Folder_SubFolder_SubFolder_ClassName{}
```

Now I use http://www.phpdoc.org/ and when I run: `$ phpdoc -d . -t docs` I get a print out like this:

[image]

Should the things like AisisCore_*path_to_class* not be in a folder called AisisCore? Am I doing something wrong in my documentation? Because honestly, this looks like a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want those things to all fall into "AsisCore", then you need to use "@package AsisCore" for everything rather than including the Subfolder pieces in the package name.

Whatever you use as the "package" name is what will be used to group classes together.  By including those Subfolder pieces in the package name string, you are telling phpDocumentor to treat, for example, "AsisCore_Template" as something separate and unrelated to "AsisCore_Template_Helpers_Loop".

Looking over the list of your output, I'd probably choose to include either zero, or at most *one*, Subfolder level in the package name.  When you then view one package's main page, you'll see that the class names themselves help group things together in the listing order, simply because you are following the PSR-0 / PEAR naming convention.

Comment: It looks like phpDoc2.x has updated the @package behavior to mimic namespacing more directly (http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/package.html), so that the underscores in your examples do get treated akin to subnamespaces.  What you should be seeing is one listing per full "namespacing" (=== "package_subpackage_subsubpackage_etc").  I do not believe phpDocumentor does any kind of "roll up and present a 'package' level view only/too".  Maybe see if https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1020#issuecomment-23270097 might cover the results you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with backslashes.

as in:

```
@package Folder\SubFolder\SubFolder
```